# How to add frontend form using custom content type?

Tags: views, 7, theming

I new to Drupal and I created a custom content type which has few fields, like donation name, value, size, etc.

I want to add these fields as a form for user which they can fill in the frontend. I want to know there are existing for this task or it can be done through core module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is usually done by giving the user permission to add the content type and presenting them with the /node/add/{content_type} page, letting them create their own page content.

Comment: can you pls explain how i can give the user permissions..

Comment: Go to /admin/people/permissions

Comment: try http://nodeone.se/en/learn-drupal-7-with-nodeone for a good start, it covers all of the basics like this question.

Answer (score 1):

An ideal solution for your problem would be to use the [webform](http://drupal.org/project/webform) module, which is used in similar scenarios and has many features out of the box.

> Webform is the module for making surveys in Drupal. After a submission, users may be sent an e-mail "receipt" as well as sending a notification to administrators. Results can be exported into Excel or other spreadsheet applications. Webform also provides some basic statistical review and has and extensive API for expanding its features.

It also has a [very good documentation](http://drupal.org/documentation/modules/webform) which will help you to get started.

Comment: The problem is it would not directly create content in his content type. [Entityforms](http://drupal.org/project/entityform) would be closer, but with his position in the Drupal learning curve, the core Content Types solution is the easiest for him to work with.

Comment: @Triskelion OP mentioned he takes data like _donation name_, _value_, _etc_, which might mean that there is a requirement for the OP to collect information of the donations made, which might contain sensitive information. And I don't find it logical to save the details of the (donating) user as a node. And with his position in the learning curve, I don't think learning webform is a bad idea if it suits his use case.